# Alarm application using timer in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to get the sound to play at a specified time but no matter what I try I can't seem to get it to work :/

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick

    alarmtime = My.Computer.Clock.LocalTime.Date.ToString + " " +
                ComboBox1.Text.ToString + ":" + ComboBox2.Text.ToString + ":" + My.Computer.Clock.LocalTime.Second.ToString + " " +
                My.Computer.Clock.LocalTime.TimeOfDay.ToString

    If My.Computer.Clock.LocalTime.ToString = alarmtime.ToString Then
        If RadioButton1.Checked = True Then
            My.Computer.Audio.Play(Label2.Text.ToString, AudioPlayMode.WaitToComplete)
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: I just tried plugging some values into your code and got this comparison: `If "2015/12/07 14:26:09" = "2015/12/07 00:00:00 2:3:9 14:26:09.5296945" Then`. The way you're trying compare times it's working.

Comment: If I were you I would forget mucking about with timers and NuGet "Rx-WinForms" so that you can use Microsoft's Reactive Extensions. You could get rid of `Timer1_Tick` and just make your code look something like this: `Observable.Timer(DateTimeOffset.Now.AddHours(1.0)).Where(Function (x) RadioButton1.Checked = True).ObserveOn(Me).Subscribe(Sub (x) My.Computer.Audio.Play(Label2.Text.ToString, AudioPlayMode.WaitToComplete))`.

Comment: @Enigmativity http://puu.sh/lMgF0/66e3f4e19e.png this is what i am setting up

Comment: That's fine. Just don't use timers - use my code. Just it in the `RadioButton1` checked event. The `Subscribe` method returns an `IDisposable` so you can deactivate a previous timer if you user turns it off. The parameter to `Timer` is a `DateTimeOffset` which you would calculate from your drop downs. Don't try to create a `String` like you've been doing as that's a bad way to do it.

Comment: @Enigmativity I'm not sure how that code works as I am used to the very "basics" of Visual basic - No pun intended

Comment: Please fix your tags - it's clear you're not using VBA here.

Comment: @timwilliams the tags are vb.net not vba...

Comment: @bytten official - Now they are...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to suggest laying your code out differently and also making some changes to how you handle your data.

I would reccomend that you use a **DateTimePicker** rather than two Text boxes as this will make sure that your time variables easier to maintain later on. In the design tab, disable **Timer1** for the moment and set the interval to 1000ms so that it's not firing too often to swamp your computer, but often enough that the alarm plays reasonably promptly.

In form design mode, the **DateTimerPicker** will show the always show the date, but at runtime, the format of the picker can be changed so that you can only select the time. This code should go in your form's load event like this

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    DateTimePicker1.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom
    DateTimePicker1.CustomFormat = "HH:mm"
End Sub
```

This code should go in your Form's variable declarations so that it's accessible to the code further down my post

```
Dim alarmtime As New DateTime
Dim alarmsound As String = ""
Dim currenttime As New DateTime
```

The timer event should only contain the code that runs each time you want to compare local time and alarm time. I've put the code to set the alarm time into the **Radiobutton1 CheckChanged** event. I'll get to that in a Mo.Note that when I set the **currenttime** variable, I've formatted it so that it is in 24hr format just like the **DateTimePicker**. When the alarm plays, I've set **Timer1.enabled** to **False** so that the alarm doesn't keep playing for the whole minute that **currenttime** matches **alarmtime**. The last line in this sub resets the alarm time to 00:00. This is because the code that changes **alarmtime** in the next sub can only add hours and minutes, not just set them to a value (a peculiarity of VB.net).

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    currenttime = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm")
    If currenttime.Hour = alarmtime.Hour And currenttime.Minute = alarmtime.Minute Then
        My.Computer.Audio.Play(alarmsound, AudioPlayMode.WaitToComplete)
        Timer1.Enabled = False
        alarmtime = New DateTime
    End If
End Sub
```

OK. Next. The code to set **alarmtime** and **alarmsound** has been placed in here so that it will only change if if select **RadioButton1**. Also if you accidentally change the **DateTimePicker1** while the program is running, it wont change the alarm time. Personally, I would use a checkbox rather than 2 radiobuttons to enable/disable the alarm. But that's just me. So. This code fires when the check status changes.

If the radiobutton is checked, it sets **alarmtime** and **alarmsound** and starts the timer. If it isn't checked, the timer is disabled and **alarmtime** is set to "00:00" for the reasons I outlined above.

```
Private Sub RadioButton1_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RadioButton1.CheckedChanged
    If RadioButton1.Checked Then
        alarmsound = Label2.Text
        alarmtime = alarmtime.AddHours(DateTimePicker1.Value.Hour)
        alarmtime = alarmtime.AddMinutes(DateTimePicker1.Value.Minute)
        Timer1.Enabled = True
    Else
        Timer1.Enabled = False
        alarmtime = New DateTime
    End If
End Sub
```

Later on though,if you want to develop the idea of an alarm, you could redesign alarm time as a class called Alarm with properties like Time as DateTime, Enabled as Boolean,AlarmSound as String and possibly its own timer so that you could have multiple alarms without having to add more timers as design time. Also you could include the code to play the alarm,snooze the alarm and kill it.This way you could use it in other programs and add code later for features such as repeating alarms

Comment: Thank you! this really helped me.

Comment: No problem.  Glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

If you're working with dates then I'd recommend using the DateTime class instead of just plain strings.

eg.

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick

    Dim alarmTime As New DateTime()
    alarmTime = alarmTime.AddHours(Convert.ToInt32(ComboBox1.Text))
    alarmTime = alarmTime.AddMinutes(Convert.ToInt32(ComboBox2.Text))

    Dim currentTime As New DateTime()
    currentTime = currentTime.AddHours(My.Computer.Clock.LocalTime.Hour)
    currentTime = currentTime.AddMinutes(My.Computer.Clock.LocalTime.Minute)

    If currentTime.TimeOfDay = alarmTime.TimeOfDay Then
        If RadioButton1.Checked = True Then
            My.Computer.Audio.Play(Label2.Text.ToString, AudioPlayMode.WaitToComplete)
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

Or better yet, just set the timer interval to the difference between `alarm` time and `LocalTime` to have it trigger at the correct time.

eg.

Add a button click event to set the alarm time in which you set the timer interval as follows:

```
Dim alarmTime As New DateTime()
alarmTime = alarmTime.AddHours(Convert.ToInt32(ComboBox1.Text))
alarmTime = alarmTime.AddMinutes(Convert.ToInt32(ComboBox2.Text))

Timer1.Interval = alarmTime.TimeOfDay.Subtract(My.Computer.Clock.LocalTime.TimeOfDay).TotalMilliseconds
```